# Blinking Button Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I make the button have the animation of blinking?

I want to add it while waiting to retrieve the location of the user, but I cannot see any example.

What I have done now is only changing the background then change it again after retrieving the location.

> button.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(this.Context, Resource.Color.primaryColor)));

Comment: Please refer to the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask documentation on how to ask a good question. As is you are not showing any effort on even attempting to figure out the issue yourself. You are looking for a tutorial or an off-site resource. You don't describe what you've tried yourself to implement this blinking animation.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I'd say use Xamarin's Animation class, but you're not asking for any gradual transitions. I would then use System.Threading.Timer:

```
private readonly Timer _blinkTimer;
```

Then in your constructor:

```
_blinkTimer= new Timer(BlinkTimerCallback);
```

Create the BlinkTimerCallback method:

```
private void BlinkTimerCallback(object state)
{
    // This is sudo code - I don't know the proper syntax off the top of my head
    if(button.BackgroundColor == red)
    {
        button.SetBackgroundColor(gray);
    }
    else
    {
        button.SetBackgroundColor(red);
    }
}
```

Then you just switch the timer off or on based on state:

To switch it on:

```
_blinkTimer.Change(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
```

To switch it off:

```
_blinkTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to have color transition?

Comment: You can use Xamarin's Animate class for this quite easily.

A good example: https://montemagno.com/animate-anything-with-xamarin-forms/

Also see "Create a custom animation extension method". Pretty much exactly what you want to do:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom